# Schedule animation on button click when document ready in AngularJS 2

Tags: animation, angular, document-ready

Some user posted an [issue on my Github project](https://github.com/thednp/kute.js/issues/29) and I simply cannot help him, as I don't use AngularJS.

**The problem**

AngularJS does it's stuff in document render as I understand but my script KUTE.js expects the elements defined by AngularJS to be already in the DOM, as KUTE.js only works if it's linked at the end of the `<body>`.

**The possible solution**

I need a way to order the code execution in a way that's native HTML5 scripting with proper execution ordering:

- HTML render
- AngularJS execution/render
- JS execution (KUTE.js)

Since the code editor here doesn't support Angular stuff, [here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/S98TV49MJmlGKZlvKK7H?p=preview) with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that Angular renders and interacts with the DOM is intrinsic to how Angular works at its core, and you can't (nor should) really do anything about that.

Anyway, the problem isn't that your library can't find the elements when the animation is triggered. In the console.log of the Tween object, the `_el: path` item correctly points to the rectangle element. The `Element not found or incorrect selector: path` error is thrown by your `selector()` function which, for whatever reason, is being called when the application loads. If your library is looking for certain elements immediately on load before Angular has had a chance to attach them to the DOM, it's not going to work.

With all of that said, I was able to get [the Plunker to work](https://plnkr.co/edit/uP9oNwI2lCJMAaHWFeJa?p=preview). The reason the `selector()` function is running on load is because it's looking for an svg element on the DOM. If you put a dummy svg with an empty path on the body of `index.html`, it prevents the selector error from being thrown. Now, when you click the button to trigger the animation, it finds the paths that are inside the Angular component template by their ids (it doesn't care whether or not they are in the same svg that it found before) and follows through with the animation.

Comment: Let me see what I can do with this solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: OK I found the problem and fixed it, the plugin was using the `.selector()` method where not needed, I should have simply used `querySelector()` for that purpose all the way. https://github.com/thednp/kute.js/commit/1d153c363adbef8d1fc7e01dc272501899816daf